# A question about the two-dimensional Ising model

Tags: quantum-field-theory, statistical-mechanics, condensed-matter, ising-model

The two dimensional square lattice Ising model reads
$$E[\sigma]=-J\displaystyle\sum_{<ij>}\sigma_i\sigma_j-h\displaystyle\sum_i\sigma_i,$$

where $E$ is the energy, $\sigma_i$ is the spin at lattice position $i$, each taking the value $1$ or $-1$ and $J$, $h$ are coupling constants. Now there is a statement (see *Conformal Field Theory* by Di Francesco etc., pp.63) that the case $J>0$ is equivalent to that of $J<0$ when $h=0$. How to understand that?

Comment: 1. Always explain your notation! Although one can guess what $E[\sigma]$ and the $\sigma_i$ are, it's not stated anywhere within the post. What does $\sum_{<ij>}$ mean? 2. *"there is a statement"* - **where** is that statement? Who made it?

Comment: @ACuriousMind, I am soryy. I will modify my post.

Comment: This really only works for bipartite lattices, a statement you never make in your question.

Comment: @NorbertSchuch I think you mean ``$\sigma_i$ is the spin at lattice position $i$, each taking the value $1$ or $-1$'', right?

Comment: No, I mean that what you say is e.g. not true on a triangular lattice, but only on square, honeycomb, ...

Comment: DiFrancesco et al.: "Unless otherwise indicated, a square lattice is used"

Answer (score 4, accepted):

See, e.g., http://physweb.bgu.ac.il/COURSES/StatMechCohen/ExercisesPool/EXERCISES/ex_5721_sol_Y12.pdf . You can divide your lattice in two lattices (the same way as a chess board is divided into white and black "lattices" and, say, replace $s_i$ by $-s_i$ for the "black lattice".